# jQuery post request Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebase, firebase-authentication, httprequest

I am making a jQuery post request in my front-end to set the identity of a client in the backend, I am passing the client's IdToken with Firebase Auth:

```
      var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
      var test1 = user.getIdToken();
      $.post('/setIdentity_learner', {idToken: test1}, () => {
        console.log("2")
      })
```

In my backend, I am receiving it with:

```
router.post('/setIdentity_learner', (req, res) => {
  console.log("passed");
  var idToken = req.body.idToken;
  // Verify the ID token and decode its payload.
  admin.auth().verifyIdToken(idToken).then((user) => {
    // Add custom claims for identity of language learner
    admin.auth().setCustomUserClaims(user.uid, {
      identity: "ll"
    })

    db.collection(ll_collection).doc(user.uid).set({
      user_review: 0,
      number_of_reviews: 0,
      email: user.email
    }).then(function() {
      admin.auth().currentUser.sendEmailVerification();
    })

  })
})
```

But everytime I run the code, the browser console does not print out "2", nor does my backend console display "passed". In my browser console. an error of :

```
nexttick.js:41 Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at Vb (jquery-1.11.3.min.js:5)
    at Vb (jquery-1.11.3.min.js:5)
    at Vb (jquery-1.11.3.min.js:5)
    at Vb (jquery-1.11.3.min.js:5)
    at Vb (jquery-1.11.3.min.js:5)
    at Vb (jquery-1.11.3.min.js:5)
    at Vb (jquery-1.11.3.min.js:5)
    at Vb (jquery-1.11.3.min.js:5)
    at Vb (jquery-1.11.3.min.js:5)
    at Vb (jquery-1.11.3.min.js:5)
```

is displayed.

What did I do wrong here?

Thank you.

Comment: "Maximum call stack size exceeded" typically means you have an infinite loop somewhere in your code. One thing I'm noticing: `getIdToken()` returns a promise, not a value. You might need to wait for the promise to resolve to pass it into your `$.post()`

Comment: Ok, that was my issue here. Thanks